# pegar o valor de uma <td> ao clicar em um checkbox da mesma linha <tr> jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Como faço para pegar um valor de uma `<td>` ao clicar em um `checkbox` que está na mesma `<tr>` em [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

Segue meu código:

**HTML**

```
   <table style="display:none;" id="tableTime">  
        <tr>    
    <td class="hora">08:00</td>
    <td class="eventoAgenda" id="0800"></td>
    <td class="idEvento" id="id0800"></td>
    <td class="statusVerde01"> <input id="iStatusVerde01" class="iStatusVerde" type="checkbox" style="width: 15px;" ></input> </td>
        </tr> 

        <tr>
    <td class="hora">08:30</td>
    <td class="eventoAgenda" id="0830"></td>
    <td class="idEvento" id="id0830"></td>
    <td class="statusVerde02"> <input id="iStatusVerde02" class="iStatusVerde" type="checkbox" style="width: 15px;"></input> </td>
        </tr>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.iStatusVerde').click(function() {  
           var teste = $('#tableTime tr td').parent().find(':nth-child(3)').html()
           console.log(teste);
```

Tentei desta forma, porém só funciona com o valor da primeira linha, e tenho varias outras linhas. Neste exemplo estou tentando pegar o valor da terceira coluna.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você está pegando todos os `td's` da tabela com a expressão `$('#tableTime tr td')`. Você deve pegar o `tr` de onde o *checkbox* está, por isso utilize o `this`. O `this` representa o elemento referente ao evento, por exemplo, o elemento que você clicou (nesse caso ele representa o *checkbox*)

Aqui tem dois exemplos de como você pode fazer isso:

```js
$('.iStatusVerde').click(function() {  

     var teste  = $(this)                       // $(this) representa o checkbox
                            .parent()              // Navega para o elemento pai (td)
                            .parent()              // Navega para o pai de td (tr)
                            .find(':nth-child(3)') // Encontra o elemento do seletor
                            .html();               // Retorna o html do elemento 

        var teste2 = $(this)                // Representa o elemento clicado (checkbox)
                            .closest('tr')  // Encontra o elemento pai do seletor mais próximo
                            .find('td') // Encontra o elemento do seletor (todos os tds)
                            .eq(1)      // pega o segundo (contagem do eq inicia em 0)
                            .text();    // Retorna o texto do elemento

        console.log(teste, teste2);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableTime">  
 <tr>    
    <td class="hora">08:00</td>
    <td class="eventoAgenda" id="0800">11</td>
    <td class="idEvento" id="id0800">12</td>
    <td class="statusVerde01"> 
      <input id="iStatusVerde01" class="iStatusVerde" type="checkbox" style="width: 15px;" /> 
    </td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
    <td class="hora">08:30</td>
    <td class="eventoAgenda" id="0830">21</td>
    <td class="idEvento" id="id0830">22</td>
    <td class="statusVerde02"> 
      <input id="iStatusVerde02" class="iStatusVerde" type="checkbox" style="width: 15px;" /> 
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: muito bom seu exemplo.. funcionou exatamente da forma que eu precisava.. valeu

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `parent()` e `find()` para navegar até o elemento pai e depois encontrar a classe `.hora`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(".iStatusVerde").click(function() {
  var valor = $(this).parent().parent().find('.hora');
  alert(valor.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="hora">08:00</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="iStatusVerde">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hora">08:30</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="iStatusVerde">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Por que não coloca esse `id` na quarta `TD` também ?

Daí é só fazer usando `closest`.

```
$('.iStatusVerde').click(function() {  
    var teste = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    console.log(teste);
```